# WiX: How to use relative path to SolutionDir

Tags: wix, installation

I have 2 folders with solutions:

MyNETProject (NET project)
MyWiXInstaller (WiXProject)

My installer needs to get files from MyNETProject\bin\Release and to pack them to installer.
How I can set path to NET project in WiX using SoultionDir variable? 
I have tried this way:

```
$(var.SolutionDir)..\MyNETProject\bin\Release
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have added a reference to your project from your wixproj, then you can use the following:

```
$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)
```

You can read more about it on the wix toolset site: [Using Project References and Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html)