# Add Zip Files to TARGETDIR in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.11

In my Visual Studio 2017 solution, I have a WiX 3 setup project that pulls in the output several other projects (libraries, executables, assets, content). Under the directory structure for the solution but not added to the solution as a project, I have a project that compiles some browser extensions using webpack. This webpack project outputs to an artifacts folder with subdirectories for each browser. Inside each subdirectory is the compiled extension with the version number included in the file name like:

- artifacts

  - Chrome

    - myextension-0.1.0.0.zip
    - myextension-0.1.0.1.zip
    - myextension-0.1.0.2.zip

At compile time, ultimately I want to include the files matching the version number i.e. myextension-\$(var.VERSION).zip into the MSI package so it can then be placed into the application folder during installation. Even when I hard-code the version number i.e. myextension-0.1.0.2.zip into the component, I get an error from light:

```
LGHT0001: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

I'm getting the directory with a define like this:

```
<?define ChromeTargetDir=$(var.SolutionDir)Extensions\artifacts\chrome\?>
```

And then my component looks like this:

```
<Component Id="ChromeExt"
             Location="local"
             Guid="GUID_HERE">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <File Id="ChromeExtension"
          Name="myextension-0.1.0.2.zip"
          Source="$(var.ChromeTargetDir)myextension-0.1.0.2.zip"
          KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

When I look in the wixobj created by candle, I see the full correct path replaced for the file where it resides on my system:

```
<field>C:\Users\me\source\repos\mysolution\Extensions\artifacts\chrome\myextension-0.1.0.2.zip</field>
```

So my question is, what is the correct way to include "arbitrary" files in my WiX project?

Comment: Checking if you got this issue resolved eventually? Beyond just copying files locally?

Comment: I gave up on the problem and just went with copying the files locally and adding them to the WiX setup project.

Comment: OK, the only thing I suggested in chat was security software interference (blocking file), but that does not make sense since you can build without version numbers. And maybe some other addin or extension installed in your Visual Studio that interferes? Maybe something related to Google Chrome? I even tested, and saw no problems on my system. Very mysterious. Do let us know if you discover what it was - somehow.

Answer (score 0):

**`1)`** ***Solution vs Project Dir***: The first thing I would try would be to replace **`$(var.SolutionDir)`** with **`$(var.ProjectDir)`** and try a recompile. I'll follow up if the problem is something else. Let's just rule that out first.

**`2)`** ***Quotes***: I also use quotes around my paths:

```xml
<?define ChromeTargetDir="C:\Sources\Packages\MyChromeExtension\Files\" ?>
```

**`3)`** ***Project Variables***: And finally you need a reference added to your project for project references and variables to work: [WiX: How to use relative path to SolutionDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259129/wix-how-to-use-relative-path-to-solutiondir).

- Maybe add: `%ProgramFiles (x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll`
- WiX Documentation: [**`Using Project References and Variables`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html)

---

***Obscure***: More obscure causes could be **lacking access rights** (file not seen by the build process and light.exe - running impersonated?). **Corrupted** file or folder? (try to replace). And whatever else might conspire against you. **Locked** files?

Comment: 1) I've tried using ProjectDir (which is the directory of the WiX project) and then using ..\ to go up directories and back down into extensions directory but that does not work.
2) Adding quotes around the variable declaration results in the same error
3) I'm using WiXUIExtension because I have a custom UI built off of mondo... I don't see how that would fix this problem. There isn't a "project" to add the output from but WiX itself doesn't depend on Visual Studio or projects (right?) so I should be able to add whatever files I want to the installer even if they are not in a project.

Comment: Maybe try to open the path you see in the wixobj output file? Maybe you already have? Do you have the reference to "something" in place? And finally the quotes?

Comment: Yes, I can copy the path directly from the wixobj file, paste it into File Explorer and it opens the directory and the file is there. I can move or rename the file so there is nothing locking it.

Comment: Oh, did you update your first comment? Or else I didn't read it properly. Does it compile when you hard code the whole path then. Full absolute path all the way to the zip file itself? If that doesn't work then there be dragons on your machine :-).

Comment: I might try to [reinstall WiX and Votive / Visual Studio Extension](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/) just to rule that out. But this is very odd. It must be a trifle of some sort.

Comment: I tried the full path and that didn't work. I tried passing in a -d on the command line to candle and that didn't work. I gave up and copied the files into the installer project directory without version numbers in the file name. I then updated my build process for the webpack project to copy the files there after build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180466/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-dewey-vozel).